# Turning off text suggestion on Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, input, browser, microsoft-edge

I've tried different solutions but they all seem to be not working.
It is breaking my autocomplete!

To setting

`autocomplete=off`

`autocomplete=new-password`
[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Placing the following script inside the HTML.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').live('focus',function(){
      $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Adding the following
`readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"`

also is not working. Any other possible solutions would be helpful!

```html
  <form>
  <span>Autocomplete-off</span> - <input class="grid--cell s-input" type="text" name="display-name" id="display-name" autocomplete="off"/>
  </br> </br>
  <span>Autocomplete-new-password</span> - <input class="grid--cell s-input" type="text" name="display-name" id="display-name" autocomplete="new-password"/> 
 </form>
```

To demonstrate this, run the above snippet, type something into the textbox, and hit the down arrow twice on Edge.

Comment: Try placing your textboxes inside <form> tag as <form autocomplete="off">.....

Comment: instead of setting autocomplete off on focus. can you try setting its attribute on document ready
$(document).ready(function(){
$(':input').attr('autcomplete','off');
})

Comment: Can you please inform us which version of the Edge browser you are using for making this test? I try to make a test with the Edge legacy 44 and Edge (Chromium) 88.0.705.63 version and I am not able to produce the said issue. I did not get text suggestion with both `autocomplete=off` and `autocomplete=new-password`.